# How to cleanly terminate a message processing in Mule 3?

Tags: mule, mule-studio

This has to be a common feature, but I can't seem to get a handle on finding it.  I have a flow like;

```
   <inbound-endpoint.../>
   <collection-splitter.../>
   <custom component.../>
   ...
```

If the custom component receives a message I want to discard with no further action, how is it accomplished?  I don't want to abort processing the remaining elements of the collection, just the one item.

For now, I have the component return null and follow it with a payload-type-filter, but that seems clumsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, transform your component into an interceptor: the component will decide to forward or not the current Mule event for downstream processing.

For this you need to implement [`org.mule.api.interceptor.Interceptor`](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.2.1/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/api/interceptor/Interceptor.html).

Read the following for more information: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Interceptors#UsingInterceptors-WritingInterceptors

Answer (score 0):

We should use message filters in mule 3 flows. setStopFurtherProcessing of MuleEventContext is not supported for mule 3 flows.

```
<message-filter doc:name="Message">
   <not-filter>
      <payload-type-filter expectedType="org.mule.transport.NullPayload"></payload-type-filter>
  </not-filter>
</message-filter>
```